# What does it mean to iterate until it reaches button.length in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this in-line java-script function that creates a paragraph, and is called when a button gets clicked. What I do not understand is the condition code in the for loop. What does it mean to iterate until it reaches button.length? (Seeing that everytime I click the button the eventListener catches it and prints out text on the browser till forever).

```
    <script>
    function createParagraph()
    {
        var para = document.createElement('p');
        para.textContent = 'You Clicked a button!';
        document.body.appendChild(para);
    }       

    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
    {
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', createParagraph);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: this iterates through all the buttons and attaches a click event listener to them - if you didn't loop, how would you attach the handler to more than one button?

Comment: `buttons.length` represents the number of items in a `NodeList`. In other words, the number of `button` elements in your document.

Answer (score 0):

## You didn't share HTML.

Basically, is binding the click event to all buttons in your HTML.

## Look at this code snippet

*Your code is binding `click` event to the buttons*

```js
function createParagraph() {
  var para = document.createElement('p');
  para.textContent = 'You Clicked a button!';
  document.body.appendChild(para);
}

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', createParagraph);
}
```

```html
<button>
Click me!
</button>
<button>
Click me!
</button>
<button>
Click me!
</button>
<button>
Click me!
</button>
<button>
Click me!
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
```

**var buttons** will receive array of all button elements on the page.
**buttons.length** is the length of this array- the count of button elements on the page.

```
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
```

The loop will iterate once for each button element that exists (the length of the **buttons** array).

```
buttons[i]
```

Refers to the i'th button element on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Let's walk through this step by step:

1) The createParagraph() function:

```
function createParagraph() {
  var para = document.createElement('p');
  para.textContent = 'You Clicked a button!';
  document.body.appendChild(para);
}
```

What this does, is it creates a `<p>` element, containing a message 'You Clicked a button!' and appends it to the DOM.

2) [QuerySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
```

It finds every element, that matches a given selector - in this case - all buttons. It returns them, in this case we store them in a variable.

3) The for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
{
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', createParagraph);
}
```

This is actually very simple. It iterates, for each of the button in the buttons array - which is our array of button elements that we created with our QuerySelector above, and adds an `EventListener` to it.
In turn, this `EventListener` handles `click` events, by running our function, which we described in step 1.

If you put this all together:

Every time you click a button (any button on the page) there will be a `<p>` element appended to the DOM, that will include the message `You Clicked a button!`.

Answer (score 0):

Watching some tutorials on 'core javaScript' will probably help you.  Specifically, learning about for loops and iterating over arrays.

In your code, you are attaching an 'event-listener' to all of your 'button' elements.  Simplified steps to accomplish this are:

1. gather all of the button elements into an array (actually it's an array-like object).  document.querySelectorAll('button').  Will look something like this under the hood of the code: [{tagName: button},{tagName: button},{tagName: button},{tagName: button}];
2. store that array to a variable  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
3. Now buttons[0] is pointing to the first {tagName:button} element.  buttons[1] is pointing to the second button in the list, etc.
4. buttons.length refers to how long the array (named buttons) is.  You want buttons[0], buttons[1], buttons[2] etc. until you've reached the end of the array.
5. When you say 'buttons[2].addEventListener('click', createParagraph), you are adding the 'click' handler to that specific button.
6. You keep iterating over the length of the array of buttons because you want to add a 'click' handler to all of them.

Comment: "In your code, you are attaching an 'event-listener' to all of your 'button' elements."  I didn't see this one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The loop will only work for same number of times as many buttons are available in the web-page . And for each iteration it will create an event listener associated to each button.
Now that the event listener is associated to each button, no matter how many times you press the button it will invoke the event associated to it.